# Docker Machine: No space left on device

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm trying to set up Docker Machine with Docker Compose.

**Scenario 1 (without Docker Machine)**
If I run `docker-compose up -d` without Docker Machine, it creates my 3 linked containers as intented (nginx+mongodb+nodejs).

**Scenario 2 (with Docker Machine)**
Then I create a VM using Docker Machine and tell Docker to talk to that machine with `eval $(docker-machine env streambacker-dev)`.

At this point, if I ssh to my docker machine and run `df -h`, I get:

[image: docker machine df -h]

If I then run `docker-compose up -d`, I get a ["no space left on device" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTB7E.jpg) while downloading the last container.

"tmpfs" seems to be indeed a bit full after that:

[image: docker machine df -h]

Checking the **--virtualbox-disk-size** option shows that it defaults to 20000 MB, which I think is what we can see as "/dev/sda1" on both pictures. So why are containers filling up "tmpfs" n and what exactly is "tmpfs"? Is is a temporary download directory? **How can I create more space for my containers?**

Thanks!

For information, I'm using *Docker Machine 0.4.0-rc2* and *Docker Compose 1.3.2*.

Comment: The [`tmpfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) has nothing to do with `--virtualbox-disk-size`. It is a filesystem (like a RAM disk) mounted in memory and nothing there is accessing your disk.

Comment: Thanks @h3nrik for that information.

Comment: check with the dangling stuff of the docker, like dangling images, dangling volumes and delete them. `docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)` and `docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -f dangling=true -q)`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Like said above, the `tmpfs` has nothing to do with `--virtualbox-disk-size`. It seems like boot2docker mounts `tmpfs` into memory, so you need to dedicate more memory to your virtualbox vm. You can do it by specifying the `--virtualbox-memory` parameter.

```
   --virtualbox-memory "1024"
Size of memory for host in MB [$VIRTUALBOX_MEMORY_SIZE]
```

Defaults:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox testA
Creating VirtualBox VM...
Creating SSH key...
Starting VirtualBox VM...
Starting VM...
$ docker-machine ssh testA
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 1.8.1, build master : 7f12e95 - Thu Aug 13 03:24:56 UTC 2015
Docker version 1.8.1, build d12ea79
docker@testA:~$ df -h /
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                   896.6M    112.7M    783.9M  13% /
```

With `--virtualbox-memory` set to `8096`

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 8096 testB
Creating VirtualBox VM...
Creating SSH key...
Starting VirtualBox VM...
Starting VM...
$ docker-machine ssh testB
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 1.8.1, build master : 7f12e95 - Thu Aug 13 03:24:56 UTC 2015
Docker version 1.8.1, build d12ea79
docker@testB:~$ df -h /
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                     6.9G    112.4M      6.8G   2% /
```

Comment: Not very intuitive, but this worked. What the heck, Docker?

Comment: Not intuitive indeed! However, this seems to be the problem with this and fixed it for me. So, +1.

Comment: Fixed the problem for me too, I don't understand how but, thank you!

Comment: Any way to increase the default size so that I don't have to specify it manually each time?

Answer (score 165):

I had the same error (`[ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'`) and solve it this way:

1 . Delete the orphaned volumes in Docker, you can use the built-in docker volume command. The built-in command also deletes any directory in /var/lib/docker/volumes that is not a volume so make sure you didn't put anything in there you want to save.

Warning be very careful with this if you have some data you want to keep

**Cleanup:**

```
$ docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

Additional commands:

List dangling volumes:

```
$ docker volume ls -qf dangling=true
```

List all volumes:

```
$ docker volume ls
```

---

2 . Also consider removing all the unused Images.

First get rid of the `<none>` images (those are sometimes generated while building an image and if for any reason the image building was interrupted, they stay there).

here's a nice script I use to remove them

```
docker rmi $(docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk '{print $3}')
```

Then if you are using Docker Compose to build Images locally for every project. You will end up with a lot of images usually named like your folder (example if your project folder named Hello, you will find images name `Hello_blablabla`). so also consider removing all these images

you can edit the above script to remove them or remove them manually with

`docker rmi {image-name}`

Comment: On Mac I had to use single quotes ( ' ) around the argument values: `docker rmi $(docker images | grep '^<none>' | awk '{print $3}')`.
Removing stopped containers can be done with `docker rm $(docker ps -qa --no-trunc --filter "status=exited")` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32723127/619659.

Comment: I had so many unused images, I reached my shell's character limit. That's why I did `docker images | grep "^<none>" | xargs docker rmi`.

Comment: Removing unneeded images helped for me.

Comment: `docker volume prune`

Comment: .. see my step-by-step description for resizing **/var/lib/docker** using **resize2fs** in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485723/docker-increase-disk-space#57711199

Comment: It helped me so i believe that indeed some capacity has been reached - so question: What is this liimtation? Can it be configured / monitored somehow?

Answer (score 93):

If you are using Docker Community Edition:

```sh
 docker system prune --volumes
```

If you are using boot2docker (docker-machine) clear the volumes that are orphaned:

```sh
 docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

Clear unused images:

```sh
 docker rmi $(docker images -q -f "dangling=true")
```

Comment: `docker system prune` helped me

Comment: `docker system prune` ftw

Comment: `docker volume prune` for just volumes, system prune will not clear the dangling volumes.

Comment: When the above doesn't clear you enough space, here's the nuclear option: `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`. Add `--force` if you must when it skips a bunch of layers that are included in multiple containers.

Comment: You don't need two commands for volumes and the rest: `docker system prune --volumes`

Answer (score 15):

A. REMOVE UNUSED IMAGES

using the docker rm or docker rmi commands you can remove the images that you don't need. Actually exist an image that helps in this task (martin/docker-cleanup-volumes). The basis is to start selectig from your images and containers list:

> docker ps -a -s

B. MODIFY THE DOCKER JSON DESCRIPTOR

it's mentioned in some forums. The idea is to increment the descriptor located in ~/.docker/machine/machines/default/config.json . The param seems to be DiskSize but i don't know if it works in other OSs (not in windows).

C. LINUX RESIZE:

in Windows OS, docker machine or boot2docker is in fact a virtualbox vm, then you can follow the procedure to resize the disk. Take care to backup the files.
The general procedure is to make a resize in virtualbox and then use an utilitary called gpartd to modify the space perceived by linux in its partitions.
There are some links to do this procedure referenced below:

- [resize vbox disk](http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/)
- [move space](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/55867/how-can-i-move-space-from-one-partition-to-another/)
- [vbox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=50661)

D. RECREATE THE DOCKER-MACHINE / BOOT2DOCKER

The idea is recreate the default docker-machine. The following commands can illustrate you. Note that as you are re-creating the boot2docker, you will lost the previous downloaded docker images.

> docker-machine rm default
>
> docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "100100" default
>
> docker-machine env default

then you can go to virtual box and see the boot2docker space with the command "df -h"

Comment: Thanks. I was working on Windows. I made it by recreating the docker-machine.

Comment: Helped the D: (recreating docker machine)

Comment: Thank you, recreating the docker-machine worked for me (I'm on windows)

Comment: I feel soo much love!

Answer (score 4):

Run `docker system df` to see what is taking up space on your docker

Then run:

```
docker system prune --all --force
```

to remove all hidden and unused containers.

`docker system prune` does not remove all unused containers.

Comment: That's the answer! I was looking for that "docker system df" right there ;)

Answer (score 2):

On docker osx / I was able to press a button 
[**Move Disk Image**]
and it successfully moved the Docker.qcow2 (presumably containing containers / images)

[image]
initially - when machines started - I was still getting a
**No space left on device error**
but it resolved shortly after.

Comment: where did you move it to that was a better location (allowed more space)?

Comment: external ssd drive

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and could not add additional space with the docker UI for mac, I installed docker with homebrew and ran the following command when creating my machine:

`docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-memory "2048" --virtualbox-disk-size "40000" default`

this adds double the space for memory and disk size to the virtualbox that I had before and you can add the settings size here that you need as you see fit

Answer (score 0):

Open `file /lib/systemd/system/docker.service` with your favorite text editor and replace the following line where `/new/path/docker` is a location of your new chosen docker directory:

```
FROM:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
TO:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -g /new/path/docker -H fd://
```

When ready stop docker service:

```
# systemctl stop docker
```

check that docker service is stopped, the following command should yield no result

```
# ps aux | grep -i docker | grep -v grep
```

reload daemon

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

Once this is done create a new directory you specified above and optionally `rsync` current docker data to a new directory:

```
# mkdir /new/path/docker
# rsync -aqxP /var/lib/docker/ /new/path/docker

# systemctl start docker
```

confirms that docker runs into new directory

```
#  ps aux | grep -i docker | grep -v grep
```

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-docker-s-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-on-ubuntu-debian-linux

Answer (score 0):

In addition to images, **container log files** can consume a lot of disk space, and there is no easy way to inspect them, especially on macOS (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78049467/2562319) for the only way I have found).

The simplest way to reclaim the disk space used by a container is to `docker rm` the container and recreate it.

You can also find the path to the log file with `docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' CONTAINER_NAME_HERE` and remove it from either your host machine's file system (if the host OS is Linux) or from the Docker Machine VM's file system (if the host OS is macOS). More details are on my [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78044877/2562319).