# How to clean Docker container logs?

Tags: docker

I read my Docker container log output using

```
docker logs -f <container_name>
```

I log lots of data to the log in my node.js app via calls to `console.log()`. I need to clean the log, because it's gotten too long and the `docker logs` command first runs through the existing lines of the log before getting to the end. How do I clean it to make it short again? I'd like to see a command like:

```
docker logs clean <container_name>
```

But it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: You could try the "--follow" or the "--since" options? If your log requirements are special perhaps you should consider enabling one of the logging plugins: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/

Comment: Instead of cleaning logs by hand which can lead to failures, you probably just want to activate log rotation and let the docker daemon handel it automatically, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67046393/is-it-possible-to-clear-a-docker-container-log-file-mid-run/75251471#75251471

Comment: From [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/): "**Warning** The `json-file` logging driver uses file-based storage. These files are designed to be exclusively accessed by the Docker daemon. Interacting with these files with external tools may interfere with Docker's logging system and result in unexpected behavior, and should be avoided".  This means that answers that suggest to simply truncate the log file must be considered **wrong**.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

First, if you just need to see less output, you can have docker only show you the more recent lines:

```
docker logs --since 30s -f <container_name_or_id>
```

Or you can put a number of lines to limit:

```
docker logs --tail 20 -f <container_name_or_id>
```

---

To delete the logs on a Docker for Linux install, you can run the following for a single container:

```
echo "" > $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container_name_or_id>)
```

Note that this requires root, and I do not recommend this. You could potentially corrupt the logfile if you null the file in the middle of docker writing a log to the same file. Instead you should configure docker to rotate the logs.

---

Lastly, you can [configure docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/) to automatically rotate logs with the following in an `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file:

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {"max-size": "10m", "max-file": "3"}
}
```

That allows docker to keep up to 3 log files per container, with each file limited to 10 megs (so a limit between 20 and 30 megs of logs per container). You will need to run a `systemctl reload docker` to apply those changes. And these changes are the defaults for any newly created container, they do not apply to already created containers. You will need to remove and recreate any existing containers to have these settings apply.

Comment: In Ubuntu you can `du -chs /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*json.log` to know how much space your containers logs are using.

Comment: In Ubuntu server 19.04 you need to create the file /etc/default/docker with command: sudo echo 'DOCKER_OPTS="--config-file=/etc/docker/daemon.json"' > /etc/default/docker and edit the file daemon.json.

Comment: Check out official documentation for configuring log rotation: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#configure-the-default-logging-driver

Answer (score 67):

The best script I found is

```sh
sudo sh -c 'truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log'
```

It cleans all logs and you don't need to stop the containers.

Credit goes to https://bytefreaks.net/applications/docker/horrible-solution-how-to-delete-all-docker-logs

Comment: Short and sweet, I like it, thanks.

Comment: Just for cleaning logs for a specific container: 
`truncate -s 0 $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container_name_or_id>)`

Comment: works for debian too.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to remove all log files, not only for a specific container's log, you can use:

```
docker system prune
```

But, note that this does not clear logs for running containers.

Comment: Great one. It might be obvious, but it's always good to remember that this does not purge the log of running containers.

Comment: Well.. this might work. But this is dangerous!! This will delete unused volumes, too.

Comment: this is a great option during development to get the sandbox cleaned up - thanks !

Comment: FYI, this does not clear logs for running containers.

Comment: @KonradKlockgether this command without the flag --volume does not delete the volumenes.

Comment: This command will clean all docker... logs, images unused, volumes unused...

Answer (score 18):

This is not the ideal solution, but until Docker builds in a command to do it, this is a good workaround.

Create a script file `docker-clean-logs.sh` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm $(docker inspect $1 | grep -G '"LogPath": "*"' | sed -e 's/.*"LogPath": "//g' | sed -e 's/",//g');
```

Grant the execute permission to it:

```
chmod +x ./docker-clean-logs.sh
```

Stop the Docker container that you want to clean:

```
docker stop <container_name>
```

Then run the above script:

```
./docker-clean-logs.sh <container_name>
```

And finally run your container again:

```
docker start ...
```

Credit goes to the user sgarbesi on this page: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1083

Comment: Don't know if it's used to work, but it's definitely not working any longer.

Answer (score 7):

Run:

```
 docker inspect {containerId}
```

Copy LogPath value

```
truncate -s 0 {LogaPath}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use logrotate as explained in this article

https://sandro-keil.de/blog/2015/03/11/logrotate-for-docker-container/

This needs to be done before launching the container.

Answer (score 4):

Solution for a docker swarm service:

```
   logging:
     options:
       max-size: "10m"
       max-file: "10"
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to do this on OSX, you need to get to the virtual machine the Docker containers are running in.

You can use the [walkerlee/nsenter](https://hub.docker.com/r/walkerlee/nsenter/) image to run commands inside the VM like so:

```
docker run --rm -it --privileged --pid=host walkerlee/nsenter -t 1 -m -u -i -n sh
```

Combining that with a simplified version of the accepted answer you get:

```
#!/bin/sh
docker run --rm -it --privileged --pid=host walkerlee/nsenter -t 1 -m -u -i -n \
    cp /dev/null $(docker inspect -f '{{.LogPath}}' $1)
```

Save it, `chmod +x` it, run it.

As far as I can tell this doesn't require the container to be stopped. Also, it clears out the log file (instead of deleting it) avoiding errors when doing `docker logs` right after cleanup.

Comment: Worked for me on MacOS (Big Sur), unlike all the other solutions posted here.

Comment: This is a good answer, but the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/) does have a warning not to interact with the log files directly. It's probably safer to just `docker rm` the container and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 none of the solutions worked for me, I kept getting 'No such file or directory'

#### This worked

- Get container ID (inspect the container)
- In file explorer open `docker-desktop-data` (in WSL)
- Navigate to `version-pack-data\community\docker\containers\CONTAINER_ID`
- Stop the container
- Open the file `CONTAINER_ID-json.log` file and trim it or just create a blank file with same name

[image]

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66196979/1907888)

Comment: For me the path was `//wsl.localhost/docker-desktop-data/data/docker/containers/*/*.log` when using git bash

Answer (score 0):

Docker's default logging driver is the [JSON File logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/), which by default has no `max-size`. This means that it stores logs as files on disk, with no rotation and no limit to how much disk space they will use.

Although it's possible to find these log files on disk and remove them by hand, that same documentation contains a warning saying that

> These files are designed to be exclusively accessed by the Docker daemon. Interacting with these files with external tools may interfere with Docker's logging system and result in unexpected behavior, and should be avoided.

#### Safe Method

As a result, the safest way to clean up the logs is to simply remove the container that the logs are associated with. If you know which container it is, you can remove it with `docker rm <container>`. If you're OK with cleaning up a lot of containers, you can use `docker system prune`.

If you aren't sure which container is taking up so much space, you may want to examine the log files. You can find the file path for a single container with `docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container>`. If your host system is linux, that file path is probably in your host system's file system, but on macOS (and probably also Windows) it will be inside the Docker Daemon's virtual machine. You can access the virtual machine with

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
```

(ref: [justincormack/nsenter1](https://github.com/justincormack/nsenter1)) and inspect the log files there.

And once you have removed the container, you might consider setting a `max-size` for the json-file logging driver, or switch to using the [local file logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/local/) instead.

#### Unauthorized Method

If you can't or won't remove the container, you can also disregard the warning in the documentation and manually clear the log file like this:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' CONTAINER_NAME_HERE | xargs docker run --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1 /usr/bin/truncate -s 0 -c
```

Answer (score -1):

If your logs have rotated like this:

[image]

Clear them with

```
truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log.*
```