# Docker - Clean up the content of files when running containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my docker container I have some logging files.

```
docker-compose-dev.yml
                     entrypoint.sh
                     web/
                        celery_logs/
                                   log1.log
                                   log2.log
                                   logn.log
```

These logs add up while tasks are running.

Is there a way or command to clean up the contents of all log files each time I run the container like so?

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Waiting for postgres..."

while ! nc -z web-db 5432; do
  sleep 0.1
done

echo "PostgreSQL started"

python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Share your Dockerfile & entrypoint script.

Comment: @vivvekyad4v done.

Comment: Add the compose file as well. Just want to check if you are using volumes etc.

Comment: there you go, added.

Comment: Logs are explicitly defined in worker volumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do a `rm -rf` inside the entrypoint script -

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf celery_logs/*
echo "Waiting for postgres..."
```

This way all the log files will be cleared whenever you launch a new container. You can give an absolute path if required.

Answer (score 0):

### Docker file (Opcional)

First, if you just need to see less output, you can have docker only show you the more recent lines:

```
docker logs --since 30s -f <container_name_or_id>
```

Or you can put a number of lines to limit:

```
docker logs --tail 20 -f <container_name_or_id>
```

*From : [StackOverFlow#41091634](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091634/how-to-clean-docker-container-logs)*

## Manual

In this case it's the better solution, manually :

```
 rm -rf celery_logs/*
```

Comment: do these logs refer to my kind of logs, or built in docker logs? mine are celery logs

Answer (score 0):

You can force recreation of the containers:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d --force-recreate
```

Also you can write the logs to the console, and then docker will be able to handle the logging using it's [own drivers](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/), which can configure max-size of log files, etc...