# Windows 10 and Docker container logs / Docker Logging driver

Tags: docker, windows-10

I'm using Windows 10 with native docker installation.

I'm looking for the location where docker save the containers logs.
In Linux, the Docker containers log files are in this location:

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/container-id/container-id-json.log
```

But where can I find it in windows 10 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check first if those logs are in (as [suggested here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/86aebb52-ed06-4d15-b164-41a7b3b1177a/location-of-docker-logs-on-a-windows-docker-host?forum=windowscontainers)):

```bash
C:\ProgramData\docker\containers\[container_ID]\[container_ID]-json.log
```

2019: The Docker `C:\ProgramData\docker` is the `Root Dir` reported by `docker info`.
2020: `DOCKER_ARTIFACTS == \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker`
(as mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518032/windows-10-and-docker-container-logs-docker-logging-driver/56518128#comment134959895_56518128) by [Ricardo Rivaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/998245/ricardo-rivaldo), for Docker version 20.10+)
(See also "[Locating data volumes in Docker Desktop (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64418064/6309)")

Regarding Docker Linux through Hyper-v, check if "[How to Delete Docker Container Log Files (Windows or Linux)](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/delete-docker-container-log-files/) " can help (from [**Jon Gallant**](https://twitter.com/jongallant)):

> 1. Run docker inspect to find your Docker log file location
> 2. Find the “Docker Root Dir” Value, mine is /var/lib/docker
>
> Your docker log file path should be `/var/lib/docker`, but if it isn’t, then change it in the command below.
>
> ```
> find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -type f -name "*.log"
> ```

[image: https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/delete-docker-container-log-files/000330.png]

The command you see in this image is based on "[How to SSH into the Docker VM (MobyLinuxVM) on Windows](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/ssh-into-docker-vm-windows/)"

> We aren’t technically going to SSH into the VM, we’ll create a container that has full root access and then access the file system from there.
>
> - Get container with access to Docker Daemon
> - Run container with full root access
> - Switch to host file system
>
> Open a Command prompt and execute the following:
>
> ```
> docker run --privileged -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jongallant/ubuntu-docker-client 
> docker run --net=host --ipc=host --uts=host --pid=host -it --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined --privileged --rm -v /:/host alpine /bin/sh
> chroot /host
> ```

Execute the find command there, and you should find the logs.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, I can find the logs into "C:\ProgramData\docker" if I switch to Windows containers mode. 
But I misspoke, I am using Windows 10 with Docker Desktop and the Linux container mode . I would like to find how to access to logs presents into /var/lib/docker/containers/[container_ID]\[container_ID]-json.log of Hyper-V / MobyVM

Thanks !

Comment: The fifth link really helped! Thanks!

Comment: I followed the path but logs are not there so therefore this answer is not correct.
Another option is that Docker is just bad software and their documentation does not provide information on this topic.

Comment: @Kaszanas Are you using WSL2? Can you try `truncate -s 0 $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container_name_or_id>)` (with `truncate` coming from [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) `C:\path\to\Git\usr\bin`)

Comment: @VonC I am not using WSL2 to be able to set a limited amount of space and resources I allocate to Docker which I have discovered is not possible within Docker configuration when using WSL2.
The command that You specified when run by Git bash returns:
```Template parsing error: template: :1:2: executing "" at <.LogPath>: map has no entry for key "LogPath"
truncate: missing file operand
Try 'truncate --help' for more information.```

Comment: @Kaszanas Strange: could you ask that in a separate question, with more details about your specific setup?

Comment: @VonC What about copying one of these logs to a local drive on Windows? I tried the following command but it always give "no such directory" error: `docker cp my-container:/var/lib/docker/containers/48339f914c0b86b902a0037143353e6a958729b288068a524e88879c1ffdd045/48339f914c0b86b902a0037143353e6a958729b288068a524e88879c1ffdd045-json.log /tmp`

Comment: @VonC Any idea regarding to this problem?

Comment: @Lorenzo Not on the top of my head: could you post a separate question showing which version of Windows/XSL2/Docker you are using, and showing that `/var/lib/...` does exist in '`my-container`?

Comment: There is a question about my problem. You may have a look at and reply it. Thanks in advance Von :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66059094/docker-cannot-access-var-lib-docker-containers-no-such-file-or-directory?noredirect=1#comment116807153_66059094

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055244/docker-error-no-such-containerpath-while-trying-to-copy-to-local-drive?noredirect=1#comment116794182_66055244

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66054166/how-to-access-docker-log-file-in-containers

Comment: All of three question, actually I just want to copy log.json file from container to local drive on Windows.

Comment: Changed (due to new version?), now is at DOCKER_ARTIFACTS == \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker

Answer (score 32):

For `Windows 10 + WSL 2  (Ubuntu 20.04), Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61`

Lets `DOCKER_ARTIFACTS == \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker`

Container logs can be found in the following location

`DOCKER_ARTIFACTS\containers\[Your_container_ID]\[Your_container_ID]-json.log`

Here is an example :

[image]

Comment: This actually works for me. Tip: on the address bar of my File Explorer, I type \\wsl$

Comment: thank you! will reference you answer in another SO thread.. after a few hours finally saw your answer

Comment: Changed (due to new version?), now is at 
    DOCKER_ARTIFACTS == \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker

Answer (score 14):

For me, using Docker Desktop for Windows on version 4.9.1 (81317), Windows 10 21H2, WSL 2 mode, the containers' folders were at

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\containers
```

Slightly different from the others.

Answer (score 8):

For `Windows 10 + Docker Desktop version 3.6.0`, the virtual path for logs and data (artifacts) is `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker` (you can copy/paste it in Explorer navigation bar).

The logs are at `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers\[containerID]\[containerID]-json.logs`

and the data is under `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\[volumeID]\_data`

**How to get containerID:**

You can find `container ID` (truncated) by running `docker ps` in a command prompt. You can also find it by clicking the `CLI` button on DockerDesktop next to the container name, the id will be in the title of the cmd window that will pop up.
Once you have the id, you can navigate to `containers\[containerID]` under the artifacts directory (`\\wsl$\docker-...` above). The log file will have the `.log` extension and its name will have the `containerID` in it. Keep in mind that it will be an enriched json format though, so not easily readable.

**How to get volumeID:**

To find a container's data (for example kafka broker topics), you need to find the id of the volumes where the data is stored. For that you will need to click on the container in DockerDesktop, then click `INSPECT` (top right). You can then scroll down to find `Mounts` configuration entries. Each mount will have a volumeID (different from containerID), and that volumeID will be part of a path similar to this one `/var/lib/docker/volumes/71f7a5992c58fdcf229c3848acb014712f34fab380bc7c712cf5a0a632fe9110/_data`. `volumeID` here being `71f7a5992c58fdcf229c3848acb014712f34fab380bc7c712cf5a0a632fe9110`.
You can then take `volumeID` and navigate to `volumes\[volumeID]` under the artifacts directory (`\\wsl$\docker-...` above) where the data will be located.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows Users who wants to delete all Docker log files on WSL 2.

The path to the docker container is correct thx to @craftsmannadeem

`\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers`

Here a command to execute on Windows to delete all log files:

`del /s \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers\*-json.log`

Bye bye Docker logs:

```
File was deleted - \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers\2012efd0ccfb8aed6291dd9a3b7b5aef507b6af4fce5b85e9306f45980db9531\2012efd0ccfb8aed6291dd9a3b7b5aef507b6af4fce5b85e9306f45980db9531-json.log
File was deleted - \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers\9e627f1fe8f3c3ab85c64f85f93942d1f077e9a6e2896b51df782b0c0c3777d1\9e627f1fe8f3c3ab85c64f85f93942d1f077e9a6e2896b51df782b0c0c3777d1-json.log
File was deleted - \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\containers\6ea8f3cb354c199bc719701f8f1e75c333f81cd2f03dca0c7a626cbcbf9ed5a0\6ea8f3cb354c199bc719701f8f1e75c333f81cd2f03dca0c7a626cbcbf9ed5a0-json.log
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use docker-compose with windows+wsl, In my case the log monitoring agent (also running as a container in docker) was not able to find the log files eventhough the path for logs was mounted as volume.

```
volumes:
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
   - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker
```

The log monitoring agent could not find logs in

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/**/*.log
```

The problem in my case was, **I was running `docker-compose up` command for the log monitoring agent from within wsl shell. When I ran it from windows powershell or cmd, the agent was able to find the logs in mounted path.**

Comment: Lifesaver, I was spinning up elasticsearch, kibana and filebeat with a few services and could not, for the life of me, work out why no logs were visible within Kibana. This was the solution, simply running docker compose from powershell instead of from within my WSL instance.

Answer (score 0):

For window system logs are located at C:\ProgramData\Docker\containers or   %APPDATA%\Docker
For Linux system logs are located at /var/lib/docker/containers

Comment: I use Wİndows, but there is not such a directory C:\ProgramData\Docker\containers (no containers folder). Any idea?

Comment: Hi have you got the result, I too don't have containers folder.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find where the logs were stored locally. (Good chance they aren't plain text any more. However, if you just need the output of the logs, you can run a command like this:

```
docker logs --details [container-name] > container-name.log
```

This will grab the logs for the container and write them to a log file in the current directory.

Note: The `--details` adds additional info to the logs like environment variables and the like, but is not required for the command to work.