# where can I find docker container logs on Microsoft Windows 10 enterprise edition operating system using Docker desktop for windows

Tags: docker, logging, windows-10, docker-desktop

I am using Docker desktop for windows.

Docker Engine
v20.10.5

I want to see the logs of a container that is not starting up due to some error. I do have a container if of the container.

The question is where can I find docker container logs on Microsoft Windows 10 enterprise edition operating system using Docker desktop for windows.

The answer [Windows 10 and Docker container logs / Docker Logging driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518032/windows-10-and-docker-container-logs-docker-logging-driver) doesn't works for me :(

Regards

Comment: You should just be able to run `docker logs container-name` to see them, or `docker run` the container without the `-d` flag so it prints its output to the console instead of starting in the background.  What part of the linked question doesn't work for you; where have you looked for the logs already?

Comment: Thanks, David for the response.  Regarding the linked question the path specified in the linked question does not exist for me.