# Docker won't open in windows server 2019 (built 1809)

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019

I created a virtual machine using the google cloud service. The machine runs windows server 2019 (build 1809) operating system. I have installed the latest docker version 4.22.1, but couldn't open it. When I double click the icon - the application starts, "thinks" for a few mintues, but then says "Docker engine stoped".

I have tried downgrading the docker version, and looked at several discussions on this site, but nothing worked. I have also tried installing the docker on windows server 2022, but it didn't work either.

For now I'm trying to make it work on windows server 2019.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

I looked at the available solutions on this website, but nothing worked.

Comment: Check your docker logs. This might help you find it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56518032/18020941