# Remove huge space occupied by docker folders

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtual-machine, disk, diskspace

I have a VM on which I have been running (for a long time) a `docker-compose` stack.

Suddenly I started getting notifications about low disk space on my machine.

I noticed the following 2 directories occupying a disproportionally large amount of space

```
/var/lib/docker/containers
```

and

```
/var/lib/docker/overlay2
```

What is the type of information held there and how can I avoid the problem of disk depletion in the future consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker save data for images and logs

For cleaning unused images and containers you can use the [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) `docker system prune` maybe with `-a --volume` options

For logs you can view response in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48029079/4871259)

Truncate logs

```
echo "" > $(docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container_name_or_id>)
```

Setup  logs rotation in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {"max-size": "10m", "max-file": "3"}
}
```

Comment: I understand that in `/var/lib/docker/containers` there is info about logs. But what's in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` ?

Comment: There is your images and containers layers. https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#image-and-container-layers-on-disk