# Mysql: forward host lookup failed: Unknown host

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

We are using docker-compose in our app and am not familiar with this part of the application we are getting this error after runnning `docker-compose up --build`:

```
Mysql: forward host lookup failed: Unknown host
```

Comment: post your .yml file and all useful info

Answer (score 5):

After an inspection to hosts list created by docker-compose:

```
$ docker network prune
$ docker network ls
$ docker network inspect <desired_network>
```

I noticed **db** was not there, so I tried to build it up and see what happens:

```
$ docker-compose run <desired_db_image>
```

Getting the correct output:

> Initializing database
>
> mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/mysql//mysql': No space left on device
>
> Fatal error Can't create database directory '/var/lib/mysql//mysql'

So you need to [free some space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909979/docker-machine-no-space-left-on-device):

```
$ docker system prune
```

Select: **y**